# How to turn off sortable rows in Yiibooster gridview

Tags: php, jquery, gridview, yii, yii-booster

I'm pretty new to Yii with Yii-bootstrap and I can't figure out why my table is still sortable.

I have an almost clean installation of Yii and I follow the instructions on the Yiibooster website for installing the booster.

To kickoff my application its nice to add some users and view the existing users.
But I don't like to sortable gridview which is generated. And I can't turn it off.

What is wrong with this code?

```
<?php

    $gridDataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('User',array());
    $gridColumns = array(array('name'=>'username'),array('name'=>'email'));

    $this->widget(
        'bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView',
        array(
            'fixedHeader' => true,
            'sortableRows'=>false,
            'headerOffset' => 40,
            // 40px is the height of the main navigation at bootstrap
            'type' => 'striped condensed',
            'dataProvider' => $gridDataProvider,
            'responsiveTable' => true,
            'template' => "{items}",
            'columns' => $gridColumns,
        )
    );

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

The variable is [`enableSorting`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseListView#enableSorting-detail) not `sortableRows`.

Comment: Sorry , i cant yet! Reputation is required